# PHP Code To Search And Replace If Found Element In CSV

Tags: php, search, csv, replace

Supposing we have a CSV created with the following items splitted by ;

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
G   H   I   J   K   L
M   N   O   P   Q   R
```

I'm trying to figure out how can I use the following code

```
$f = fopen($file, "r");
while ($row = fgetcsv($f,'',';')) {
    if ($row[1] == 'H') {       
        echo ('FOUND ! ');      
    }
}
```

To open the file and after that for the item `H` found in the CSV file, I would like to replace the `K` item with `K+replace`. How is this done?

I want to use this to conditionally insert values in a million entries CSV, I mean if one element is found to update this item with other value.

I am choosing CSV due to the fact that MySQL taking more than 0.5 seconds to search-find-update/replace per item. (everything done in a loop).

Comment: have you looked at str_ireplace()?

Comment: Why do this in a loop? If H is a value in a column in a MySQL table then an update query of UPDATE table SET (k column to whatever I want) WHERE H column = 'H' will do it.

Comment: I am introducing thousands of elements through a FOR loop so basically for each $i I am testing if the item already exist in MySQL DB if it exist I am updating the entry. So do the math 1000000*0,5s = ... Not fiable at all :( This is why I am trying with CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to open the file and read it one line at a time like you have, but then open an "output" file and write to that file one line at a time as you loop through each line in the "source" file.  So basically

```
$f = fopen($file, "r");
$o = fopen($output_file, "a");
while ($row = fgetcsv($f,'',';')) {
  if ($row[1] == 'H') {         
    $row[4] = '??'; // whatever you want to replace K with
     echo ('FOUND ! ');        
  }
  fputcsv($o,$row,';');    
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what "not working" means? I did see one typo in my code... `$o` had the same `$file`, should have a different filename `$output_file` (edited)

Comment: yes it's working, just needs an else to complete rest of values ... btw can this be done by using the SEEK of the line to be replaced ?

Comment: the problem with using `fseek` and `fwrite` is that unless the replacement value is equal or less characters in length, it's going to overwrite things.  IOW, it doesn't "bump up" the rest of the data in the file.  In order to "bump up" the rest of the data, you will have to grab all the data from the `fseek` point to EOF and put it in a variable - which considering your file is so big, probably will not work out for you.  So the easiest thing to do is just do it one line at a time to a 2nd file like what I've shown.

Comment: yes... I understand thank you ! one more thing... do you think that csv method is faster than INSERT INTO mytable on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ?

Comment: also you're right, i forgot about an `else` to also write the lines not needing change.  Well you don't really need an `else` for that, see edited code

Comment: I don't know if it would be faster to insert into your db instead of a csv......it might possibly be more efficient to just import the whole complete output file than do an insert, since it's just straight writing instead of searching.

Comment: yes I am talking about constructing the DB ... when it increase over 200.000 records to check if item exist and insert/update procedure takes 0,4-0,7s/item for MyISAM and 0,6-1,2/item for InnoDB system and testing right now the CSV taking 2.2-2.6s/item. A true pain in the ... if you have thousands of items in FOR loop ... is there any way to reduce these intervals to... maybe 0,1-0,2s/item ?